# Codeigniter Session is not working when uploaded to host

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a `PHP` project using `Codeigniter` and its working perfectly with the `localhost`. I'm using `Xampp 3.2.1` and when I upload the project to the server and try to load the project its working and show the login page. When I enter credentials and login, it redirect me to the home page of my project and when I try to navigate to any other location it redirects me to login page. Please can any one help me on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cause because `Codeigniter` In-built session is not supported in the sever. What you can do is Use `PHP Sessions`

> refer to this link if you want more details -
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

What you can do is use `start_session()` in you controller and use `$_SESSION` to save your session data and access it.

If you have More than one Controller the approach is different,
You have to create a controller in your project's `\application\core\` call `MY_Controller`(Its okay if you want to use a different Name). The Code of the Controller Should be

```
<?php 
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!isset($_SESSION))// to avoid A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() 
        { 
           session_start(); 
        }           
    }
}
?>
```

and extend all your controllers in your `\application\controllers\` with this controller in order to access the `session` globally

Now use

> $_SESSION['data_name'] =  $Your_Data;

to set values to `session`

and in log out function just use `session_unset()` to clear your current session data

Hope It helps :)